# @RequestBody usage with multiple arguments

Tags: java

This has probably be asked before, but I can't for the life of me use the similar examples I can find online to sort out my understand of spring annotations.

I have a post method:

```
   @PostMapping(value = "/changeFriendName", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> changeFriendName(@RequestBody Friend friendNameToChange, @RequestBody String inputName){
    System.out.println(friendNameToChange.getName());
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello " +friendNameToChange.getName() + ", lets change to = " + inputName, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

where:

```
public class Friend {

//@NotNull
String name;
//LocalDateTime lastContact;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Trying to get some understanding so keeping it simple at the minute.

As soon as I have a second input parameter, I can't seem to understand how to create the JSON payload using postman to get an OK response.

I have a number of things, the latest payload:

```
{
    "object":{
        "name":"roberto"
    },
    "string":"dave"
}
```

I can't seem to get the understanding of how the POJO is parsed from the payload.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can declare multiple `@RequestBody` parameters.  You will need to make a new class that combines both; e.g.,

```
public class RequestDto {

  private Friend friend;
  private String inputName;

  // ... getters, setters ...

}
```

and then you can do

```
@PostMapping(value = "/changeFriendName", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> changeFriendName(@RequestBody RequestDto requestDto){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
        "Hello " + requestDto.getFriend().getName() + ", lets change to = " + requestDto.getInputName(),
        HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense thanks. Is this standard practice for each request type hitting an endpoint?

Comment: Also would a JSON payload for this new RequestDto POJO take this form: {
    "friend":{
        "name":"roberto"
    },
    "inputName":"dave"
}

Comment: Yes, the json will look like that exactly.  And yeah I would generally expect each `POST` endpoint to have its own dto/pojo as input.